# MIPS - My loop doesn't perform quite how it should

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to construct a while loop in Mars MIPS assembly however I have run into a bit of a problem, where the loop itself works, however the action of halving the number with each pass of the loop doesn't seem to initiate after the first round.

Below is the loop I have:

```
div:
sra $s0, $t1, 1 #halves the number in $s0

li $v0, 1
add $a0, $zero, $s0 #Prints out the number in $s0
syscall

li $a0, 32
li $v0, 11  #Prints out a space
syscall

loop:
blt $s0, $s4, exit  #Loops to the start of div until it reaches 1

j div

exit:
li $v0, 10  #This is the exit.
syscall
```

All help is welcome, as I have a terrible feeling a rookie mistake is being made here.

Comment: Use MARS debugger to step through the program

Comment: `$t1` doesn't change within your loop, so `sra $s0, $t1, 1` will give you the same result every iteration.